# Setting the value of an UIView subclass custom parameter in IB

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

I created a subclass of an UIView called smartView.
Then I created a NSInteger parameter viewID.

Now in the IB I change the class of a standard UIView to my smartView.

My question is how can I supply a value for my viewID parameter in IB?

Is it possible? If not, is there another way besides "Tag" parameter to give a UIView component a unique id?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to supply that value in IB would be to create a IB Plug-in.

See [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html) for a tutorial, and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004323-CH1-SW1) for the Apple Reference Document.

Comment: Hey, thx, for answer but unfortunetly you can not do IB Plug-in's for the iPhone. At least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an IBOutlet for your smartView in the view controller then you can access it like:

```
self.mySmartView.viewID = _viewID;
```

Comment: Yep I will probably use that although I wanted to go with the IB entirely without codeing in ViewController